# How to reduce cyclomatic complexity in a if condition?

Tags: java, cyclomatic-complexity

In an if condition as following:

```
if( condition1 || condition2 || condition3 || condition4 || condition5)
```

Where conditions are independent of each other, the code complexity tends to be high, is there a way to refactor this logic to reduce complexity?

The conditions here can represent methods which do a validation and return a boolean value.

I am adding a code snippet for clarity:

```
public void doSomething(boolean val, boolean val2, boolean val3, boolean val4, boolean val5, boolean val6)
    {
        if(val || val2 || val3|| val4|| val5|| val6)
        {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("hello world");
        }
    }
```

The complexity of the above snippet is 7.

How can I reduce it?

Comment: you should show more code because this code has no cyclomatic complexity : you have a single path.

Comment: Why are you concerned about cyclomatic complexity? Would you be willing to reduce readability if you could reduce cyclomatic complexity?

Comment: As I understand, cyclomatic complexity is the number of linearly independent paths through the code. An easy way to reduce would be to use `|` instead of `||` since this would force an evaluation of all the conditions each time. I have a hard time seeing the improvement, though.

Comment: Why have you got a method signature that takes 6 booleans? I'd care more about readability & usability than cyclomatic complexity

Comment: @OleV.V. My guess why someone would care about the cyclomatic complexity, is because some tool like Sonar is put into use, it complains about a bunch of localized "problems" and coding standards, and then developers have to "fix" their code until the thing stops nagging. Managers can then pat themselves on the shoulder for having taken steps to "improve" the code base even though the big picture, the architecture, could still be a crumbling mess. Or maybe I'm just bitter.

Comment: @G_H The PMD Code static analyser will complain about too much cyclomatic complexity and then our code will not be approved by our peers =S

Answer (score 1):

May be get boolean flags populated for each condition and using those flags in if statement. That would improve readability as well in my opinion.

Comment: But that would not solve the complexity issue right?.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case I would make this code more universal:

```
public void doSomething(boolean... val) {
    for (boolean v : val) {
        if (v) { 
           System.out.println("hello");
           return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("hello world");
}
```

This will allow you do not carry about number of arguments in method, if your logic inside this method is *really* this (i.e. do ACTION #1 if any of arguments is `true`, otherwise do ACTION #2).

Answer (score 0):

After your edit :

> "Complexity of the above snippet is 7"

I think that the problem is the tool you are using to measure the complexity.

If you replace it

```
  if(val || val2 || val3|| val4|| val5|| val6)
```

by

```
   boolean condition = val || val2 || val3|| val4|| val5|| val6;          
   if(condition)
```

what is the complexity now ?

---

In development, cyclomatic complexity generally refers to potential paths in the code flow. It is often enough related to nested conditional blocks.

We talk about code that has a important cyclomatic complexity as arrow code as the nested levels draw a kind of arrow.

In your sample code it is not a problem as you have only three possible paths :

```
public void doSomething(boolean val, boolean val2, boolean val3, boolean val4, boolean val5, boolean val6)
    {
        if(val || val2 || val3|| val4|| val5|| val6)
        {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("hello world");
        }
    }
```

- First path : `if(val || val2 || val3|| val4|| val5|| val6)`
- Second path : `else{`
- Third path : code between the `else` and the end of the method

Less a code have possible paths, more is it easier to read, to test, and to maintain it.

In your too simple case you could reduce the complexity by using not the `else` statement. Which delete a potential path :

```
public void doSomething(boolean val, boolean val2, boolean val3, boolean val4, boolean val5, boolean val6)
    {
        if(val || val2 || val3|| val4|| val5|| val6)
        {
            System.out.println("hello");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("hello world");           
    }
```

---

But clearly your examples are too simple to manifest serious issues related to complexity.
Here is a modified version of your sample code where the complexity questions about refactoring the code to reduce the cyclomatic complexity.

```
public void doSomething(boolean val, boolean val2, boolean val3, boolean val4, boolean val5, boolean val6)
    {
        if(val || val2 || val3|| val4|| val5|| val6)
        {
            if (condition){
                  if (val8 && val9){
                     ...
                  } 
                  else {
                      if (condition2 && condition3){
                         System.out.println("hello");
                      }
                  }
            }

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("hello world");
        }
    }
```

Generally to reduce the cyclomatic complexity you have to reduce the number of possible paths. You can achieve it :

- by avoiding not required `else`
- grouping condition statements that are separated while it could be a single statement that
- exiting of the method when a condition allows to do it and not waiting for a single exit point.

---

Comment: A small note: a `return;` is needed in the if block, in the snippet without the else, to keep the same output.